# LoggedIn processor with federated authentication

Tags: federated-authentication, azure-ad

I added a custom processor to my `sitecore/processors/loggedin` configuration, which is read fine when a user logs in through the standard Sitecore interface. However, if a user logs in with Azure AD using federated authentication in Sitecore 9.0.1, that processor doesn't appear to be firing when I step through with my VS debugger.

Is there a different set of logged in processors I should be looking at for this login method?

Comment: are you extending your processor class from UserProvider (namespace Sitecore.Security.Accounts)?

Comment: No, from Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn.LoggedInProcessor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn` pipeline.

There are a bunch of fedauth-related pipelines (like `owin.cookieAuthentication.*`) defined in the `\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config` file that you might want to explore.